# Problem using recursive method in c++

Tags: c++, class, methods, recursion

I have a class, defined in a .h like this

```
#ifndef JLLABOUR_H
#define JLLABOUR_H

class JLLabour{

public:
JLLabour(int, int);

double* recursivefft(double*,int);
void FFT(int*);

~JLLabour();

private:
int width;
int height;
};

#endif // JLLABOUR_H
```

and in my .cpp I have the definition of my recursive function, the problem is that when I call it again , during compilation it doesnt allow me to continue because the method has not been defined yet. I dont know how to solve this, please help.

```
#include <JLLabour.h>

double* JLLabour::recursivefft(double* x,int asize){
//operations and declartions...
//...


  even = recursiveFFT(sum,m); //<-- the problem is here, in the recursion.
  odd = recursiveFFT(diff,m);

// more operations....
return result;
}
}
```

FYI I am compiling under Linux, using Qt because Im developing a graphic app...

Comment: what are the types of `sum`, `diff`, `even`, `odd`, and `m`?

Comment: What you think is the problem probably isn't. Please post the error you are getting.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

C++ is case sensitive. Your method is called `recursivefft` not `recursiveFFT`.

Comment: Using an IDE instead of some text-editor would probably have prevented this.

Comment: OMG I knew this, and still didnt notice it. that was it, Im so so sorry, such a silly mistake.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y The editors I know all have automatic completion.  If it's used, then this sort of error can't occur, and if it isn't, then presumably an IDE wouldn't help either.  (It must be possible to have two names differing only in case.)